Integrate Nut-Sdk java module in React Native
Scanned devices result not getting? Integration of Nut-Sdk Java module for scanning Ble-devices.
I have created NutSdkMoudle java file as I am implementing Native Module of React Native so that I can use all the native java features in my React Native component.
Can any one tell me what is wrong in the code as I am beginner in java also I am providing the documentation.
Link :-  https://docs.google.com/document/d/1HUifX0mdUNvGiju6MIrKzEXua3Uy_hl6/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=101408469640564465700&rtpof=true&sd=true
SDK link :- https://github.com/nut-tech/nut-sdk-android
also added this package in my "Interactivity" file
But I am not getting any scanned result of ble-devices though initialisation and binding is done properly have open id too for verification
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.util.Log;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Callback;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Promise;

import com.nutspace.nut.api.model.BleDevice;
import com.nutspace.nut.api.BleDeviceConsumer;
import com.nutspace.nut.api.BleDeviceManager;
import com.nutspace.nut.api.callback.ScanResultCallback;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class NutSdkModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule implements ScanResultCallback {
    private BleDeviceManager mManager;
    private BleDeviceConsumer bleConsumer;
    private ScanResultCallback scanResultCallback;
    private ArrayList<BleDevice> scannedDevices = new ArrayList<>();

    ArrayList<BleDevice> mBleDeviceList = new ArrayList<>();

    ReactApplicationContext reactContext;

    NutSdkModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);
        this.reactContext = reactContext;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "NutSdkModule";
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void initializeBleManager() {
        mManager = BleDeviceManager.getInstance(getReactApplicationContext());
        mManager.addScanResultCallback(this); // Register this class as the callback for scan results
        Log.d("NutSDKModule", "Initializing BleDeviceManager: " + mManager);
        if (mManager != null) {
            Log.d("NutSDKModule", "BleDeviceManager initialized successfully");
        } else {
            Log.e("NutSDKModule", "Failed to initialize BleDeviceManager");
        }
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void bindBleService() {
        try {
            if (mManager != null) {
                bleConsumer = new BleDeviceConsumer() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean bindService(Intent intent, ServiceConnection serviceConnection, int i) {
                        // Bind the Bluetooth service
                        return getReactApplicationContext().bindService(intent, serviceConnection, i);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void unbindService(ServiceConnection serviceConnection) {
                        // Unbind the Bluetooth service
                        getReactApplicationContext().unbindService(serviceConnection);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onServiceBound() {
                        // Implement method if needed
                    }

                    @Override
                    public Context getApplicationContext() {
                        return getReactApplicationContext(); // Return the application context
                    }
                };
                mManager.bind(bleConsumer);
                Log.d("NutSDKModule", "BleService bound successfully");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("NutSDKModule", "Failed to bind BleDeviceManager: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void unbindBleService() {
        try {
            if (mManager != null) {
                mManager.unbind(bleConsumer);
                Log.d("NutSDKModule", "Unbinding BleDeviceManager: " + mManager);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("NutSDKModule", "Failed to unbind BleDeviceManager: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void startScanning() {
        try {
            if (mManager != null) {
                mManager.startScan();
                Log.d("NutSDKModule", "Starting scanning: " + mManager);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("NutSDKModule", "Failed to start scanning: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void stopScanning() {
        try {
            if (mManager != null) {
                mManager.stopScan();
                Log.d("NutSDKModule", "Stopping scanning: " + mManager);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("NutSDKModule", "Failed to stop scanning: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    // This method will be called when a BLE device is scanned
    @Override
    public void onBleDeviceScanned(BleDevice device) {
        // Process the scanned device here
        Log.d("NutSDKModule", "Found device: " + device);
        scannedDevices.add(device); // Store the scanned device
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void getScannedDevices(Callback successCallback, Callback errorCallback) {
        try {
            // Return the list of scanned devices to the React Native code
            successCallback.invoke(scannedDevices);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            errorCallback.invoke(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}


and My React Native code as follows
const [scannedDevices, setScannedDevices] = useState([]);
  const [isScanningBle, setIsScanningBle] = useState(false);
  const [connectionStatus, setConnectionStatus] = useState("");

  //request to on bluetooth
  const requestBluetoothPermissions = async () => {
    try {
      const result = await checkMultiple([PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.BLUETOOTH_SCAN]);
      console.log("Permission status:", result);

      if (result !== "granted") {
        const requestResult = await request(PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.BLUETOOTH_SCAN);
        console.log("Request result:", requestResult);

        if (requestResult === "granted") {
          console.log("Bluetooth permission granted.");
          // Do something after permission is granted
        } else {
          console.log("Bluetooth permission denied.");
          // Handle the case when permission is denied
        }
      } else {
        console.log("Bluetooth permission already granted.");
        // Do something if permission is already granted
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(
        "Error checking or requesting Bluetooth permission:",
        error
      );
      // Handle error
    }
  };

  async function getBluetoothState() {
    const isEnabled = await BluetoothStatus.state();
    console.log(" ~ getBluetoothState ~ isEnabled:", isEnabled);
    if (!isEnabled) {
      Alert.alert(
        "Enable Bluetooth",
        "Please enable bluetooth in order to use Tracking Feature."
      );
    }
  }

  //intitialization & clean up effecct of stop scanning if component unmount
  useEffect(() => {
    getBluetoothState();
    const initializeBleManager = async () => {
      // Request Bluetooth permissions if running on Android
      if (Platform.OS === "android") {
        await requestBluetoothPermissions();
      }

      // Initialize the BleDeviceManager
      await NutSdkModule.initializeBleManager();
      // Binding
      await NutSdkModule.bindBleService();
    };

    initializeBleManager();

    return () => {
      // Stop scanning when the component unmounts
      // NutSdkModule.stopScanning();
    };
  }, []);

  const nutSdkModuleEmitter = new NativeEventEmitter(NutSdkModule);
  //as java is emitting the device scanned data we are receiving it here
  useEffect(() => {
    // Subscribe to scan result events
    const scanResultSubscription = nutSdkModuleEmitter.addListener(
      "onBleDeviceScanned",
      (device) => {
        setScannedDevices((prevDevices) => [...prevDevices, device]);
      }
    );

    return () => {
      // Clean up subscriptions when the component unmounts
      scanResultSubscription.remove();
    };
  }, []);
  console.log("Scanned Devices:", scannedDevices);

  //scanning function
  const handleScanToggle = () => {
    if (!isScanningBle) {
      NutSdkModule.startScanning(); // Start scanning
    } else {
      NutSdkModule.stopScanning(); // Stop scanning
      // setScannedDevices([]); // Clear scanned devices
    }
    setIsScanningBle((prevIsScanning) => !prevIsScanning);
  };```


